# Connexion to postgresql db using zendframework

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework

i'm working with zend-framework 3. i want to make connection to postgresql, but i dont work. There is my 
global.php file

```
return array ( 
   'db' => array ( 
      'driver' => 'Pdo', 
      'dsn' => 'pgsql:dbname = bdd;host = localhost', 
      'driver_options' => array ( 
      ), 
   ), 
);
```

there is my local.php file

```
return [
    'db' => [
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
    ]
];
```

i have activated pgsql extension and pdo_pgsql. 
Can someone help me please ???

Answer (score 0):

In global do (remove space after = )

```
return array ( 
   'db' => array ( 
      'driver' => 'Pdo', 
      'dsn' =>'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=pagila;user=postgres;password=postgres', 
      'driver_options' => array ( 
      ), 
   ), 
);
```

in your local file do

```
  return array ( 
       'db' => array ( 

          'dsn' =>'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=pagila;user=postgres2;password=postgres2', 

       ), 
    );
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr Coder  for your response. I have his probleme `C:\wamp64\www\projetzend\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php:282
Message:
Connect Error: could not find driver
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\projetzend\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo.php(255): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection->connect().` I have activate this extension :  php_pgsql, php_pdo_pgsql